# What is a good way to set a default value in a sorted ComboBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

When I initialize a combobox with text contents like so, where `eo` is some object with a `ToString()` override:

```
foreach (EncodingInfo ei in Encoding.GetEncodings()) {                  
    Encoding e = ei.GetEncoding();
    encodeObject eo = new encodeObject();
    eo.Name = ei.DisplayName;
    eo.Value = ei.Name;
    int targetIndex = this.targetEncodingBox.Items.Add(eo);
}
```

I can set this to be the default value by using

```
this.targetEncodingBox.SelectedIndex = targetIndex
```

However, when the box is actually sorted, and the data initially entered into the box using the `Add()` method is not sorted, the default index is kept while the box is re-sorted, resulting in an entirely different value being selected almost all of the time.

A basic solution for this is to look up the generated value that the combobox would display and use `FindStringExact`:

`this.targetEncodingBox.SelectedIndex = this.targetEncodingBox.FindStringExact("utf-8 -- Unicode (utf-8)");`

However, this results in other problems. The string in question may depend on the user's operating system' language settings in this particular case. This can't be known beforehand.

Thus another way I've found is to manually find the name of the encoding a second time and set the `SelectedIndex` after the box is fully populated, using the same convention for concatenating the acronym name and translated name as used in the definition for `encodeObject.ToString();`.

```
        foreach (EncodingInfo ei in Encoding.GetEncodings()) {
            if (ei.Name == "utf-8") {
                this.sourceEncodingBox.SelectedIndex = this.sourceEncodingBox.FindStringExact(ei.Name + " -- " + ei.DisplayName);
            }
        }
```

Note: the definition of the class `encodeObject` below:

```
    private class encodeObject {
        public string Name;
        public string Value;
        public override string ToString() {
            return Value + " -- " + Name;
        }
    }
```

This actually works, and does exactly what I want, yet the solution seems quite clunky to do something that should really be a single call. Is there a better way of achieving this?

Comment: Keep it simple and sort the collection yourself, before adding it to the combobox.

Comment: Can you use SelectedItem instead of SelectedIndex?

Comment: Why don't you store the reference of the `eo` object that should be selected by default, and once the sorting is done, just set `targetEncodingBox.SelectedItem = savedDefaultEo`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Hans commented you need to create that list and store it to a variable.
Since the available encodings are unlikely to change anyway, this should happen in some class constructor or when you load your settings.

This variable then can be re-used anywhere you need it, it also can be easily updated & sorted as you like.

After this step the rest is trivial, create a variable with a default value/index, and once a ComboBox was assigned this list just set the SelectedValue/SelectedIndex value to your default value/index.